Biexponential fit doesn't match with data
I have a set of data for which I am trying to fit a biexponential function. So far, I have done
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import csv
from pylab import genfromtxt
import scipy

twofifty = genfromtxt("t vs delta E (250C).txt");

t = twofifty[:, 0]
de = twofifty[:, 1]*10e3

def func(t, f_1, tau_1, f_2, tau_2):
    return f_1*np.exp(-t/tau_1)+f_2*np.exp(-t/tau_2)

guess = (0.7, 100, 0.3, 200)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, t, de, guess)
print(popt)
plt.plot(t, de, label="data")
plt.plot(t, func(de, *popt), label="fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

But the graph comes out as shown below.

I'm not sure what I need to change to get the correct results. I have changed the scale of the y axis since it was in the order of 10^4 and included some guess values which allowed me to get the following results,
[-1.46219808e+02 -4.99772483e+05  2.42937404e+01 -1.94190603e+01], but I know they are not the correct values as the fit is not right and they are negative values. As you can tell, from the biexponential equation I am trying to extract the amplitudes (f_1 and f_2) and decay time (tau_1 and tau_2). I know for the amplitudes the sum has to be 1, hence my predictions of 0.7 and 0.3, but as I don't really know what tau will be, only that they will be of the order of 10^-1 or 10^-2. How can I smooth out the fit line, because as it's evident, it doesn't actually fit the data? What can I change to make it fit the data?
When doing the change of plt.plot(t, func(de, *popt), label="fit") to plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="fit"), as recommended, the plot comes out to be

This smooths out the curve, but still doesn't seem to match/fit the data.

It looks like plt.plot(t, func(de, *popt), label="fit") ought to be plt.plot(t, func(t, *popt), label="fit"). Does that help?

@NickODell thanks for the suggestion, this does seem to smooth out the curve. Unfortunately, it still seems to me that it still doesn't fit well with the data. I have updated the question to include your recommendation and the result it gives me. Do you have any other suggestion as to why it may not fit the data? It could be that this is the best fit I can get, of course.

@Reinderien added a link to the data

Your are facing a simple problem flat baseline when t <= 0 cannot be captured by your model which will have to grow asymptotically.
Censuring data when t <= 0, we got:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, stats, special

x, y = np.genfromtxt("https://pastebin.com/raw/h2HnULEz").T
q = x >= 0
x = x[q]
y = y[q]

def model(t, f1, tau1, f2, tau2):
    return f1 * np.exp(- t / tau1) + f2 * np.exp(- t / tau2)

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, y, maxfev=10000)

By removing the flat baseline before and forcing more function evaluations we get a bit more fitness:

But this is clearly not satisfying and certainly does not capture the initial flat baseline.
On the other hand your data strongly looks like a negative version of a Log Normal distribution. Writing the model and fitting:
def model2(t, A, sigma, loc, scale):
    law = stats.lognorm(sigma, loc=loc, scale=scale)
    return - A * law.pdf(t)

popt2, pcov2 = optimize.curve_fit(model2, x, y, p0=[0.1, 0.5, 1, 10])

Gives in comparison a better fit:

If we keep the whole data, without any precaution but an educated guess we got:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, x, y, p0=[30, 5, -30, 5])


If we clamp the asymptotic behaviour around t < 2. we get almost a good fit, but not better than the Log Normal:
def model(t, f1, tau1, f2, tau2):
    y = f1 * np.exp(- t / tau1) + f2 * np.exp(- t / tau2)
    y[t < 2] = 0.
    return y


This is strong evidence that the main problem with your fit is the asymptotic behaviour of the model that cannot be captured without clamping your model or censoring your dataset.

thank you very much! I understand what you mean, if the model is not censored/clamped then it won't fit properly with the data, instead it will go over. I just have a follow up question, I have been trying to use the bounds function of 'optimize.curve_fit' to only have the model fit from the minimum until the end of the asymptotic behaviour, but I get an error or 'x0 is infeasible. I changed the guess parameters, but I kept getting the same error, what do you think is the issue?

It means your p0 is not contained within bounds. You probably have narrowed your bounds without adapting the initial p0 value which is "out of bounds" or "infeasible". At least this is what I can say from your comment. Bounds are for p0 = (x0, y0) in the format [(x0min, y0min), (x0max, y0max)].

Apologies, I don't think I phrased properly what I wanted to do. I'm trying to fit the model for a specific interval of data, i.e. 5 < x < 40, but without removing any of the data points, just refining the model to fit only that range. From what I understand, bounds would not give me that result. I saw in other posts they use Boolean masks to achieve this, do you have any advice as to that may be implemented? Or any other suggestions I can use?

Bounds apply only on fitted parameters. Mask is what you are looking for.
